# SSL sites gives Common name Invalid

Tags: ssl, san

SSL Error when assessing by IP address

I have an IP address as `192.0.2.13`. On nslookup, it shows the answer as example.com

Now on assessing the IP address `https://192.0.2.13` itself it gives, SSL error as Common name invalid and but if I tries to access `https://example.com`, it loads fine. Also, I can see SAN configuration as 
DNS name : example.com
DNS name : examplem.com

Now, I want to know should I need to add IP address to SAN config as well?

Comment: While technically you can, you shouldn't. HTTPS is not really useful with IP addresses in URLs. It is also more complicated to add IP addresses in certificates (but not impossible). The real question being: why do you want to access the website through `https://192.0.2.13` insteaed of `https://example.com/`?

Comment: Most CA won't sign a certificate with IP addresses in SAN or Common name.

Comment: I have a example.com and I want to add IP address in SAN so that it won't shows me a error - Common name Invalid